# Find a function that makes the following diagram commutes.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, retraction

Find a function that makes the following diagram commutes.

Here is the diagram: For $n \geq 0.$ Find a function $r: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \{0\} \rightarrow S^n$ filling in the dotted arrow in the following diagram so that the diagram commutes.

> $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> S^n @>{id_{S^n}}>> S^n\\
> @VVV @VVV \\
>  \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \{0\} @>{r}>> S^n
> \end{CD} $$

Where the first vertical arrow is the inclusion map, the second vertical arrow should not exist but I am not skillful in drawing commutative diagrams.  and the arrow that has the function $r$ above it should be dotted line because we are searching for this function $f.$

**My guess is:**

I can take the function to be $r(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}.$ Is my guess correct? I am not sure why I should divide by $|x|,$ or this part should be adjusted to the $n+1$ norm? I do not know.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is the commutativity you want? Do you want $r\circ \iota = \operatorname{id}_{S^n}$, where I represent the inclusion by $\iota:S^n\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: @MPW yes exactly this is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by $\vert x\vert$ you mean $\Vert x\Vert$.Then your function is alright. You need to divide by $\Vert x\Vert$ only for sake of well definedness.

This proves $S^n$ is a retract of $\Bbb R^{n+1} -\{0\}$.

It is in fact a strong deformation retract.

Comment: Could you please show me the well definedness proof?

Comment: You need the final modulus of $x$ to be 1, that's why you performed the division.